# Set an event for a div with multiple class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set an event on a div whos parent has a class="classA classB"; My css is being applied but i cant figure out how to specify it with jquery. How do i set an event with jquery for this  class combination

```
$('[class=classA classB]').live('click', function () {
        alert('a');
    });
```

html

```
<div class="classA classB">...moredivs...</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain the classes in the selector, like this:

```
$('.classA.classB').live('click', function () {
    alert('a');
});
```

Without a space in-between, the selector will only match element that have **all** the classes.
Note: the class order *doesn't* have to match!

Comment: A quick note too: the actual CSS selector that does this does not work in IE6 - but that doesn't affect JavaScript of course.